# Android add a rounded line to my picture? border

Tags: android

How can I add a rounded border to my picture?

[image]

I d like to draw that "blue" line there on the border.

Thanks

edited:
this is not a control, this is a bitmap, drawable, on a mapview

Comment: I believe this question is answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012556/border-over-a-bitmap-with-rounded-corners-in-android/12543803#12543803

Answer (score 1):

Use a 9-patch image for the background of your control.

Comment: this is not a control, this is a bitmap, drawable, on a mapview