# How to create a circle clippath from an image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-custom-view

Imagine that I have a rectangle image. How could I create a style like the next one?

[image]
[image]

I mean, cropping the image into a circle, add the border, the shadow and the gross /shine effect. Until now, I only have tried this snippet code to crop the image: [Cropping circular area from bitmap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932805/cropping-circular-area-from-bitmap-in-android) but just that. I have no idea how to do the remaining components in Android.

Comment: I post a round corner implementation, hope it help you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19858771/1294681

Answer (score 16):

An easy way to achieve this effect is to use `Canvas.drawCircle()` and a `BitmapShader`:

```
BitmapShader s = new BitmapShader(myPhoto, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

Paint p = new Paint();
p.setShader(s);

myCanvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, p);
```

To do the shadow, simply call `Paint.setShadowLayer()` on the paint (this will only work if you draw the effect into an offscreen `Bitmap` or if your `View` uses a software layer – set by calling `View.setLayerType()` –).

The border can be drawn by drawing another circle on top, using the `Paint.Style.STROKE` style (that you can set by calling `Paint.setStyle()`).

Finally you can draw the gloss by drawing a circle, oval or `Path` on top of your very first circle. You'll need to use a `LinearGradient` shader on your paint and you'll also need to clip the gloss. You can do this in two ways:

1. If you are drawing the entire effect into a `Bitmap`, which is what I would recommend, simply set the paint's `Xfermode` to a `new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)`.
2. If you are drawing the effect directly on screen you can simply use `Canvas.clipPath()` to set a circular clip. Note that this will work with hardware acceleration only as of Android 4.3.