# border for rounded image in android

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview, border, rounded-corners

I am setting rounded image in imageView. Now, I want to set border for rounded image view.

If it is simple rectangle image then we can do it by setting background color for that image view and setting padding. So it will look like it has a border.

But How I can set border for rounded image view ?

My code to create rounded image for square

```
    public static Bitmap getRoundededImage(Bitmap bitmap, int diameter) {

    Bitmap output = null;

    try {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        int rectX = (bitmap.getWidth() - diameter) / 2;
        int rectY = (bitmap.getHeight() - diameter) / 2;

        final Rect rect = new Rect(rectX, rectY, rectX + diameter, rectY
                + diameter);

        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = diameter;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        // draw border
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 20);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output;
}
```

I tried to search and found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012556/border-over-a-bitmap-with-rounded-corners-in-android). I tried this solution but it didn't work. When I applied this solution nothing changed in image.

Please help me to resolve this or guide me in a right path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655264/how-to-add-a-shadow-and-a-border-on-circular-imageview-android seehere

Comment: You can draw path as border along with your bitmap.

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal can you throw some lights on how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I am observing that, you are drawing some bitmap over view, then simply you calculate your boundary co-ordinate , and draw path along the boundary, by the using `canvas.drawPath()`, its might me help you.

Please go through this then you can get some ideas.

[Draw in Canvas by finger, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android)
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/Drawpath.htm

This is one more example over rounded corner images
http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

This is example of drawing Rounded corner over some ractangle

```
canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 100, 100, 200), 6, 6, paint);
```

There are lots of api for getting boundary corner , jsut you need only some calculation according to your images,

Hope this information will help you.